# Mean of a sliding window in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of values that I would like to report the average in windows along a smaller slide.

For example, for a vector of the following values:

```
4, 5, 7, 3, 9, 8
```

A window size of 3 and a slide of 2 would do the following:

```
(4+5+7)/3 = 5.33
(7+3+9)/3 = 6.33
(9+8)/3 = 5.67
```

And return a vector of these values:

```
5.33, 6.33, 5.67
```

Is there a simple function that will do this for me? If it also returned the indices of the window starts that would be an added bonus. In this example that would be 1,3,5

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/TTR/html/MovingAverages.html)?

Comment: Can you give some background on this "slide" idea?

Comment: @J.M - I hadn't! Thank you! I'm about to see how it works.

Comment: @Shane - Yes! I'm sorry that wasn't clear. The slide is the number of positions/indices you move to start computing the next window of averages. So rather than the next window starting after the end of the last there is some overlap when the slide is smaller than your window size. The idea is to smooth out the data points a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same question. Now, I found it useful the function "rollapply".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Function `rollapply` in package zoo gets you close:

```
> require(zoo)
> TS <- zoo(c(4, 5, 7, 3, 9, 8))
> rollapply(TS, width = 3, by = 2, FUN = mean, align = "left")
       1        3 
5.333333 6.333333
```

It just won't compute the last value for you as it doesn't contain 3 observations. Maybe this will be sufficient for your real problem? Also, note that the returned object has the indices you want as the `names` of the returned vector.

Your example is making an assumption that there is an unobserved 0 in the last window. It might be more useful or realistic to pad with an `NA` to represent the missing information and tell `mean` to handle missing values. In this case we will have (8+9)/2 as our final windowed value.

```
> TS <- zoo(c(4, 5, 7, 3, 9, 8, NA))
> rollapply(TS, width = 3, by = 2, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, align = "left")
       1        3        5 
5.333333 6.333333 8.500000
```

Comment: BTW, I once wrote about a usage of this function to implement the notion of "quantile loess" : http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/04/quantile-loess-combining-a-moving-quantile-window-with-loess-r-function/

Comment: You may add a 0 at the end of x (`x<-c(x,0)`) to get the last element of answer.

Comment: @mbq; that is making a strong assumption that the observation is 0. I had been mulling this point and T-Burns is making the same assumption (an unobserved 0). I would prefer perhaps to pad with NA and pass in the `na.rm = TRUE` argument to `mean`. The answer won't be the same as what the OP requested, but it seems more useful. I'll edit my answer to include this.

Comment: @ucfagls Yet this is easy to change and as you said this assumption was made by the OP. On the other hand, I would be even more restrictive and removed the last average.

Comment: Thanks! Especially for noting the last value as zero assumption, I hadn't considered that. I definitely care about that last window!!

Answer (score 16):

Rollapply works great with a small dataset. However, if you are working with several million rows (genomics) it is quite slow.

The following function is super fast.

```
data <- c(runif(100000, min=0, max=.1),runif(100000, min=.05, max=.1),runif(10000, min=.05, max=1), runif(100000, min=0, max=.2))

slideFunct <- function(data, window, step){
  total <- length(data)
  spots <- seq(from=1, to=(total-window), by=step)
  result <- vector(length = length(spots))
  for(i in 1:length(spots)){
    result[i] <- mean(data[spots[i]:(spots[i]+window)])
  }
  return(result)
}
```

http://coleoguy.blogspot.com/2014/04/sliding-window-analysis.html

Comment: Quite helpful. But be aware, that window=3 will return the average of 4 (!) values, unless you add a `-1` (to the range) and a `+1` (to the loop).

Comment: Just as a hint, this function is not as fast as you might expect: I modified it to calculate a median instead of the mean and used it for a 17 million row data set with a window size of 3600 (step=1). It took 25 minutes to complete. In addition, I wrote a Go program for the same task and it finished within 21 seconds. But the problem isn't the language, it is the algorithm. For this algorithm, the window size is of critical importance. I think the options from the TTR package are a much better option if you are looking for a simple moving mean calculation (look at the other answers).

Answer (score 5):

This simple line of code does the thing:

```
((c(x,0,0) + c(0,x,0) + c(0,0,x))/3)[3:(length(x)-1)]
```

if `x` is the vector in question.

Comment: This does not return what the asker wanted, but 5.33 5.00 6.33. However, it looks quite interesting. Can you explain your idea, because I don't get it.

Comment: @Henric I use this trick frequently, yet user1414's code return this roll with slide 1, not 2, as intended by OP. Check out `(c(0,0,x)+c(0,x,0)+c(x,0,0))/3` to see what I mean (and how does it work). The proper formula would be: `(c(0,0,x)+c(0,x,0)+c(x,0,0))[1:(length(x)-3)*2+1]/3` (we must cut 0-padding at the beginning and select even elements then.

Answer (score 4):

I can do this easily in Matlab and duck while you downvote me:

```
%given vector x, windowsize, slide 
idx1 = 1:slide:numel(x);
idx2 = min(numel(x) + 1,idx1 + windowsize);  %sic on +1 here and no -1;
cx = [0;cumsum(x(:))];  %pad out a zero, perform a cumulative sum;
rv = (cx(idx2) - cx(idx1)) / windowsize; %tada! the answer!
```

as a side effect, `idx1` is the index of the element in the sum. I am sure this can be easily translated into R. The idiom `first:skip:last` in Matlab gives the array first, first+skip, first+2skip, ..., first + n skip, where the last element in the array is no greater than `last`.

**edit**: I had omitted the averaging part (divide by `windowsize`).

Comment: +1 Not tada, rv/windowsize ;-)

Comment: This marg... comment box is too narrow for this code, so I've posted a new answer.

Comment: Thanks, but MATLAB isn't free!!

Comment: @T-Burns: octave is free, however; also R is close enough to Matlab that this code can easily be translated. In fact, @mbq did that..

Answer (score 4):

```
library(zoo)
x=c(4, 5, 7, 3, 9, 8)
rollmean(x,3)
```

or

```
library(TTR)
x=c(4, 5, 7, 3, 9, 8)
SMA(x,3)
```

Comment: Does this work for 2D matrices? Like how? If the window size is 3*3 as an example

Comment: it is only one direction

Answer (score 3):

[shabbychef's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/mean-of-a-sliding-window-in-r/3072#3072) in R:

```
slideMean<-function(x,windowsize=3,slide=2){
 idx1<-seq(1,length(x),by=slide);
 idx1+windowsize->idx2;
 idx2[idx2>(length(x)+1)]<-length(x)+1;
 c(0,cumsum(x))->cx;
 return((cx[idx2]-cx[idx1])/windowsize);
}
```

EDIT: Indices you're looking for are just `idx1`... this function can be easily modified to return them also, but it is almost equally fast to recreate them with another call to `seq(1,length(x),by=slide)`.

Comment: thanks for translating. I figured it would be an easy exercise, and I learned some R from it

Comment: My updated answer is use `fromo::running_mean` from the bleeding edge version of my [fromo package](https://github.com/shabbychef/fromo/tree/dev).

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the window means and the index of the first value of the window:

```
#The data
x <- c(4, 5, 7, 3, 9, 8)

#Set window size and slide
win.size <- 3
slide <- 2

#Set up the table of results
results <- data.frame(index = numeric(), win.mean = numeric())

#i indexes the first value of the window (the sill?)
i <- 1
#j indexes the row of the results to be added next
j <- 1
while(i < length(x)) {
    #This mean preserves the denominator of 3
    win.mean <- sum(x[i:(i+2)], na.rm = TRUE)/win.size
    #Insert the results
    results[j, ] <- c(i, win.mean)
    #Increment the indices for the next pass
    i <- i + slide
    j <- j + 1
    }
```

Various caveats apply: haven't tested this against anything but your sample data; I believe that appending to data frames like this can get *really* slow if you have lots of values (because it'll copy the data.frame each time); etc.  But it does produce what you asked for.

Comment: Please don't downvote without providing a comment.  How am I supposed to know what's wrong?

Comment: It wasn't me, but this is slow (but not much slower than `rollapply`).

Comment: wasn't me either, but as mentioned by yourself, pre-allocation of the result object will help with the speed issue. One trick, if you don't know, or it is tedious/difficult to determine, the size of the result object you need. Allocate something reasonable, perhaps pre-filling with NA. Then fill in with your loop, but add a check that if you are approaching the limit of the preallocated object, allocate another big chunk, and continue filling.

Comment: @mbq; Speed of results, whilst important, isn't the only consideration. Instead of having to reinvent the while and handle all the indexes etc in the custom solutions, the one-linear that is `rollapply` is much easier to understand and grep the intention of. Also, `rollapply` is likely to have had many more eyeballs checking its code than something I might cook up one afternoon. Horses for courses.

Comment: ucfagls, thanks for adding some info on pre-allocating when you don't know the ultimate size of the object - that's helpful.  And while I agree that rollapply is probably almost definitely the way to go, I a) wanted to provide an example that would calculate the edge cases with less than three values, and b) just wanted to use `while()`, which I've yet to have a use for ;)

Comment: Changing `[i:(i+2)]` to `[i:(i+win.size-1)]` would make the code more general, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a convolution operation. The implementation in R uses FFT internally and you are unlikely to beat it with loops and such things.

```
> vals=c(4, 5, 7, 3, 9, 8, 0)
> convolve(x=vals, y=c(1, 1, 1)/3, type="filter")
[1] 5.33 5.00 6.33 6.67 5.67
```

If you want to extract every second result.

```
> tmp <- convolve(x=vals, y=c(1, 1, 1)/3, type="filter")
> tmp[0:2*2+1]
[1] 5.33 6.33 5.67
```